# When decrypting caesar cipher via brute force, cannot print right attempts

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, brute-force, caesar-cipher

I'm attempting to decrypt a caesar cipher via brute force. I can encrypt something fairly easily, and then I want the program to decrypt a message using brute force. What I want to happen is for python to print out all 26 shift values of the encrypted message. This is my code:

```
message = input("What message do you want to use: ")
shiftValue = int(input("What would you like to shift the message by: "))
encryptedMsg = ""

for character in message: 
    if character.isalpha() == True: 
        if character == character.lower():
            x = ord(character) - 97 
            x += shiftValue 
            x = x % 26  
            encryptedMsg += chr(x + 97) 
        else:
            x = ord(character) - 65
            x += shiftValue
            x = x % 26
            encryptedMsg += chr(x+65)
    else: 
        encryptedMsg += character

print(encryptedMsg)

def decrypt(encryptedMsg):
    i = 0
    shiftValue = 0
    while i < 26:                  
        attempt = ""
        for char in encryptedMsg:
            if char.isalpha() == True:
                x = ord(char) - 97
                x = x + shiftValue
                x = x % 26
                attempt += chr(x+97)
            else:
                attempt += char
            print(attempt)
            i += 1
            shiftValue += 1

decrypt(encryptedMsg)
```

Once I run this, I am given the following code on the python shell. Lets say the message variable is "My name is Daniel" and I use a shiftValue of 2. This is what is printed:

```
i
ib
ib 
ib s
ib sg
ib sgt
ib sgtm
ib sgtm 
ib sgtm s
ib sgtm sd
ib sgtm sd 
ib sgtm sd k
ib sgtm sd ko
ib sgtm sd koc
ib sgtm sd kocy
ib sgtm sd kocyv
ib sgtm sd kocyvd
z
zs
zs 
zs j
zs jx
zs jxk
zs jxkd
zs jxkd 
zs jxkd j
zs jxkd ju
zs jxkd ju 
zs jxkd ju b
zs jxkd ju bf
zs jxkd ju bft
zs jxkd ju bftp
zs jxkd ju bftpm
zs jxkd ju bftpmu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 3 lines of `decrypt()` are executed at every iteration of `for char in encryptedMsg`. This is wrong. You want to finish creating the decrypted string before you print it.

Another problem is that your program doesn't handle uppercase characters properly. A quick fix would be to use `lower()` to convert everything to lowercase before processing it.

Try this:

```
def decrypt(encryptedMsg):
    i = 0
    shiftValue = 0
    while i < 26:                  
        attempt = ""
        for char in encryptedMsg.lower():
            if char.isalpha() == True:
                x = ord(char) - 97
                x = x + shiftValue
                x = x % 26
                attempt += chr(x+97)
            else:
                attempt += char
        i += 1
        shiftValue += 1
        print(attempt)
```

---

#### Edit:

A more "pythonic" way of implementing loops is to use syntax like `for x in range(y):`. Also, `if x == True` can always be simplified to `if x:`. Here's a simplified version of your code with a single iterator variable (`shiftValue`):

```
def decrypt(encryptedMsg):
    for shiftValue in range(26):
        attempt = ""
        for char in encryptedMsg.lower():
            if char.isalpha():
                x = (ord(char) - 97 + shiftValue) % 26
                attempt += chr(x+97)
            else:
                attempt += char
        print(attempt)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my code so that it now will encrypt for upper and lower case letters, but when I run it, Python just prints out blank statements when printing out the 26 solutions. Do you know why? see edited first post

Comment: No. But after `if char.isalpha():`, try adding something like `if char.isupper():` `base = ord('A')` `else:` `base = ord('a')`, then replace `97` with `base` in the following lines.

Comment: Thank you! Sorted the problem!